# Boost 1.58.0 build with ndk-build for arm64-v8a

Tags: boost, android-ndk, arm64

I'm trying to build Boost 1.58.0 with ndk-build for `arm64-v8a` but I encountered a problem with it.

When I run `bjam`, it finishes with error `unrecognized command line option '-m64'`.

And I found out something is wrong on "the Performing configuration checks" part
such as :

```
- 32-bit : no
- 64-bit : yes
- arm : no
...
```

I guess the `arm` field should be `yes` and it is quite different when I build it for `armv7-a`. The corresponding build for `armv7-a` has been always succeeded.

[Environment]

- host : ubuntu linux x86
- NDK : android-ndk-r10e (google)
- gcc : 4.9
- android platform : android-21

The build command used is

```
./bjam toolset=gcc-ndk10.android.21.arm64v8a.4.9 link=static \
    runtime-link=static target-os=linux --stagedir=output/arm64-v8a \
    --disable-filesystem2 -sICONV_PATH=/home/weareff/local.r10/arm64-v8a/include
```

My `user-config.jam` file is the following:

```
# NDK 10, android-21, arm64-v8a, 4.9, 
using gcc : ndk10.android.21.arm64v8a.4.9 : /home/weareff/external/android-ndk/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/aarch64-linux-android-gcc :
<compileflags>--sysroot=/home/weareff/external/android-ndk/android-ndk-r10/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64
<compileflags>-D_LITTLE_ENDIAN
<compileflags>-D_POSIX_THREADS=1
<compileflags>-D_POSIX_SOURCE
<compileflags>-DANDROID
<compileflags>-march=armv8-a
<compileflags>-mtune=cortex-a53
<compileflags>-fpic
<compileflags>-ffunction-sections
<compileflags>-funwind-tables
<compileflags>-fstack-protector
<compileflags>-fno-short-enums
<compileflags>-fomit-frame-pointer
<compileflags>-fno-strict-aliasing
<compileflags>-finline-limit=64
<compileflags>-Wno-psabi
<compileflags>-Os
<compileflags>-O2
<compileflags>-g
<compileflags>-I"/home/weareff/external/android-ndk/android-ndk-r10/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64/usr/include"
<compileflags>-I"/home/weareff/external/android-ndk/android-ndk-r10/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64/usr/local/include"
<compileflags>-I"/home/weareff/external/android-ndk/android-ndk-r10/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include"
<compileflags>-I"/home/weareff/external/android-ndk/android-ndk-r10/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/arm64-v8a/include"
<linkflags>-L"/home/weareff/external/android-ndk/android-ndk-r10/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64/usr/lib" -stdlib=libstdc++
<archiver>/home/weareff/external/android-ndk/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ar
;
```

The output messages are as follows:

```
Performing configuration checks

    - 32-bit                   : no
    - 64-bit                   : yes
    - arm                      : no
    - mips1                    : no
    - power                    : no
    - sparc                    : no
    - x86                      : no
    - combined                 : no

Building the Boost C++ Libraries.


    - has_icu builds           : no
    - lockfree boost::atomic_flag : no

Component configuration:

    - atomic                   : not building
    - chrono                   : not building
    - container                : not building
    - context                  : not building
    - coroutine                : not building
    - date_time                : building
    - exception                : not building
    - filesystem               : building
    - graph                    : not building
    - graph_parallel           : not building
    - iostreams                : not building
    - locale                   : not building
    - log                      : not building
    - math                     : not building
    - mpi                      : not building
    - program_options          : not building
    - python                   : not building
    - random                   : not building
    - regex                    : building
    - serialization            : not building
    - signals                  : not building
    - system                   : building
    - test                     : not building
    - thread                   : building
    - timer                    : not building
    - wave                     : not building

...patience...
...found 1318 targets...
...updating 86 targets...
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time/build
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-ndk10.android.21.arm64v8a.4.9
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-ndk10.android.21.arm64v8a.4.9/release
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-ndk10.android.21.arm64v8a.4.9/release/link-static
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-ndk10.android.21.arm64v8a.4.9/release/link-static/runtime-link-static
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-ndk10.android.21.arm64v8a.4.9/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-ndk10.android.21.arm64v8a.4.9/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/gregorian
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-ndk10.android.21.arm64v8a.4.9/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_month.o
aarch64-linux-android-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-m64'

    "/home/weareff/external/android-ndk/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/aarch64-linux-android-gcc"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall --sysroot=/home/weareff/external/android-ndk/android-ndk-r10/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64 -pthread -m64  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_DATE_TIME_STATIC_LINK -DDATE_TIME_INLINE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-ndk10.android.21.arm64v8a.4.9/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_month.o" "libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_month.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-ndk10.android.21.arm64v8a.4.9/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_month.o...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-ndk10.android.21.arm64v8a.4.9/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_weekday.o
aarch64-linux-android-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-m64'
```

Comment: But what's the bottom line: does it build the ilbs for aarch64?

Comment: It fails to build libs for aarch64. so I need a help.

Answer (score 1):

The architecture checks for arm says "no" should caused by the file in {boost_root}/libs/config/checks/architecture/arm.cpp which has following contents:

```
#if !defined(__arm__) && !defined(__thumb__) && \
    !defined(__TARGET_ARCH_ARM) && !defined(__TARGET_ARCH_THUMB) && \
    !defined(_ARM) && !defined(_M_ARM)
#error "Not ARM"
#endif
```

This file could not be complied by the arm64 gcc and we can patch it by adding "**aarch64**", so it become:

```
#if !defined(__arm__) && !defined(__thumb__) && \
    !defined(__TARGET_ARCH_ARM) && !defined(__TARGET_ARCH_THUMB) && \
    !defined(_ARM) && !defined(_M_ARM) && !defined(__aarch64__)
#error "Not ARM"
#endif
```

This may make the architecture checking recognize this is arm platform.

Answer (score 1):

you can try follow configure options:

```
    BS_CONFIG_EXTRA := -d2 -q toolset=gcc architecture=arm abi=aapcs address-model=64
    ./bootstrap.sh && ./b2 $(BS_CONFIG_EXTRA)
```

I have successfully compiled the boost 1.58.0 library in aarch64 hardware.

Regards.

Comment: For my situation only the architecture=arm and address-model=64 were needed but this helped me to finally get the build.